# Queue Implementation using linked list - How does the front pointer get updated automatically?

Tags: c#

The below code works, can someone please help me understand why -

The new node is appended to the rear node in the else statement below.

However, after its execution the new node gets chained onto the front node.

How does this take place ? Are there any references here that I am failing to see ?

```
public class QueueNode
{
    public int data;
    public QueueNode next;

    public QueueNode(int d)
    {
         data=d;
    }
}

public class Queue_using_LinkedList
{
    public QueueNode front;
    public QueueNode rear;
}

public class GfG
{

    /* The method push to push element into the queue*/
    public void push(int a,Queue_using_LinkedList ob)
    {
        QueueNode newNode = new QueueNode(a); //Create new Node

        if(ob.front==null)
        {
            ob.front = ob.rear = newNode ;    //Front and Rear both reference the new Node
        }
        else
        {
            ob.rear.next = newNode;           //This adds new Node to Front
            ob.rear = newNode;                //This makes Rear as the latest added Node 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after its execution"? Nothing happens after `push` has completed (until the next `push` call, anyway). Could you give an example of how you're using it, and at which point you're confused? (I really want to help you, but that'll be easier to do when the question is clearer.)

Comment: (It's also a fairly unusual API for a queue, with unconventional naming too. If this has been given to you as an example, I'd be somewhat wary of this as a teaching source.)

Comment: @Chris: No, after the first call, both `front` and `rear` will refer to the same node, because of `ob.rear = ob.front;`.

Comment: Ah yes. You are right, Daisy. Actually loading up the code and running it makes it clearer how it works. To OP. Are you missing the fact that the node in `rear` is the last node of the chain that starts with `front`?

Comment: @Chris, "node in rear is the last node of the chain that starts with front" .. how did this come to be ?

Comment: @Daisy, "both front and rear will refer to the same node, because of ob.rear = ob.front" , if that is the case, at any point of time front and rear should be mirror copies of one another, right ? That is not the case. New nodes get added to front and rear contains only the latest added node.

Comment: @AbhishekPoojary: No, that's only the case when the list contains *one* node, because that's when `ob.front` and `ob.rear` are set to the same reference. Later calls to `push` change `ob.rear` to refer to a different node.

Comment: Hi @Daisy, I have updated my code for clarity. I still don't get how this line works --> ob.rear.next = newNode;

Comment: @AbhishekPoojary: So what do you not understand about it? It sets the reference in the current queue tail to be the new node... and then the next statement sets the queue tail itself to be the new node.

Comment: Hi @Daisy, appreciate if you could check out my latest comment on Hele's post below, to understand my query.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear which aspect is confusing you. I suspect you don't understand how references work at the moment - perhaps http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html would help you?

Comment: Hi @Daisy, thanks for sharing the article. But then it only reinforces my confusion --> ob.rear = newNode. This statement breaks the shared reference between front and rear. Changes made to rear should not get reflected to front henceforth, but they do.

Comment: @AbhishekPoojary: You need to differentiate between the values of `front` and `rear` changing (so they refer to different node objects) and the values *within the node objects* changing. `ob.rear = newNode;` doesn't change `ob.front` at all, but if `ob.rear` and `ob.front` refer to the same object, then `ob.rear.next = newNode;` would be visible through `ob.front` as well - until either `ob.rear` or `ob.front` is changed to refer to a different node.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly:

```
Queue_using_LinkedList q = new Queue_using_LinkedList();
new GfG().push(3, q);
new GfG().push(4, q);
new GfG().push(5, q);
QueueNode xp = q.front;
while (xp != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xp.data);
    xp = xp.next;
}
```

prints

```
3
4
5
```

When the initial node is added to the queue, both `front` and `rear` point to the same initial node. So when further nodes are added, they get added to `rear`, which is also the front.

Take a look at the image at https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/circular-queue-program.jpg .

Comment: Hi @Hele, ob.rear.next = n; //This updates the front node, ob.rear = ob.rear.next; //Then why dorsn't this update the front node again ?

Comment: Because `ob.rear` in `ob.rear = ob.rear.next;` is simply a reference. You're reassigning the reference to the new node. `ob.rear` is not the front node itself - it simply points to it. So when you update `ob.rear`, it points to the new node.

Comment: Hi @Hele, I have updated my code for clarity. Considering your example where we insert 3,4,5 one after other.. on the last call to push, after this line execution --> ob.rear.next = newNode; rear becomes 4,5. So if front is referencing rear why doesn't that become 4,5 too ? Instead it becomes 3,4,5.

Comment: `rear` is a pointer to a node. As such, it cannot possibly hold a value like "4,5". It can only point to a node that has `data=4` and `next` set to some other node having `data=5`.

Comment: Besides this, your statement "front is referencing rear" does not make sense at all. `front` references a `QueueNode` object that `rear` also references.